# How to access hosted server file directory from remote machine through front end web page

Tags: java, file, directory

I have a front end web page developed in JSF with a button named `View Logs` which will open the file `directory["C:\results"]` of contains few logs. Hosted this in server `machine1`.

Problem:

When I access this web page from `machine2` and click on `View Logs` it will open the file directory in machine1. But, my expectation is whoever access the web page and click on view logs respective machine1 logs directory should open in their machine.

Note: User has access to that file `directory["//W1171346/C/results"]`

How to write this in java?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Then just open `"//W1171346/C/results"` instead?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. But you cannot access files on the machine the user user the browser on from the browser. Nor from the web server.